# Heating system problem that kept happening at the house part far away from the heat boiler

Tags: water-heater, gas, heat

Not enough heat at the front house part far away from the heat boiler. The front house part had baseboard install but with the heat pipe through back of the house first, I am guessing that the heat energy is losing to the atmosphere before reaching the front house part.

What are some possible major reasons aside from mine that making the problem persist? Is it just because that heating system power isn't enough. I am sure that heat pipes aren't leaking.

It is a water heat using gas.

Notes: 1) Hot water heating 2) steel finned tube 3) It is controlled by one thermostat throughout the first floor(one unit on first floor but as large as the two combine in the second floor); two units on the second floor had its own boiler and separate thermostats respectively (so three boiler and three thermostats total) 4) Three Separate boiler is used in different units and only one pump is being used for first floor

Comment: How many stories are involved, vertically speaking?

Comment: This happens in 1350 sqrt ft living area at the first floor(total 4050 sqrt, 20 ft x 68 ft three family building) @ThreePhaseEel

Comment: Is the hydronic boiler on the first floor or in a basement/crawlspace?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel It is installed on the first floor.

Answer (score 1):

Some information is needed. Is this system hot water or steam? What type radiation is installed; cast iron radiators, cast iron baseboard, in the wall convectors, copper or steel finned tube? You said it is a 3 family building so how is the heat controlled? Does each apartment have it's own thermostat or is it a single thermostat? Is the system zoned? If it is zoned, how is it zoned?  Separate pumps or zone valves or a combination of both? Has the system been updated or is it original. You need to answer the above questions so people can make informed solutions to the problem. Sorry for all the questions about your heating system but we are not at your residence and trouble shooting from far away is difficult.

Comment: 1) Hot water heating 2) steel finned tube 3) It is controled by one thermostat throughout the first floor(one unit on first floor but as large as the two combine in the second floor); two units on the second floor had its own boiler and seperate thermostats respectively (so three boiler and three thermostats total) 4) Three Separate boiler is used in different units and only one pump is being used for first floor  Notes: Some body I asked suggested to seperate the heat cycle into front and back part to increase the fluid pressure, do you agreed or recommended? Thanks in advanced

Comment: Steel finned tubing is not usually used for hot water heating, It is however used for steam heating . This system could have originally been a steam system converted to a hot water system. (just a guess)  From  what you write is seems that each housing unit (apartment) has it's own heating boiler. If that is the case,  fixing the problem would be easy. My self, I would call an experienced heating company, probably one with some older employees who have extensive knowledge in a wide range of hot water/ steam systems for an opinion. You may have a unique, system.

Comment: Fully agree, tough to troubleshoot over the internet, I do HVAC work but not on boilers got the basic cert many years ago but you would want someone that has more experience with your specific type, if steam in my state it takes the highest level license since these are the most hazardous or can be if not correctly repaired.+